# inserting a entity id on a URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I want to send the ID of a entity to another page with the link.

```
class FrontPage(FuHandler):
    def get(self):
        tuts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Tutorial ")
        self.render('front.html', tuts=tuts)
```

on the front.html i have something like:

```
{% for tut in tuts %}
<a href="/tutview?tut_key={{ tut.id }}"><div id="FrontPageTutorialTitle">{{ tut.title }}
</div>
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But the links are always 'tutview?tut_key='

Comment: Are you *sure* your `tut`s have an `id` attribute? Are you sure it's not `ID` or `key` or something?

Comment: yes i can see it on the Datastore Viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the key has the id. Tut is an instance of a Model, key gets a instance of a key and only then the id is accessible

```
<a href="/tutview?tut_key={{ tut.key().id() }}">
```

Comment: Should be tut.key.id for Django forms.